# Pass url parameter into a shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress

Background of my question: I created over 300 slideshows. In my WordPress page/post they are activated with a shortcode i.e. [masterslider id=15].

I pass the value (id=15) as an url-parameter to my custom-template.
i.e. //url?nmbr=15. That works. I can echo the value, I can echo the complete shortcode [masterslider id="15"] but the slider doesn't start to show pictures.

of course, I can create one page with 100 shortcodes which will make the page very slow. I can create 100 pages with one slider but I don't like that.

Some of the fifty different code lines I tried in my own-template.php are:

```
<?php if (get_query_var('nmbr')) print '[masterslider id=$nmbr]' ?>
<?php if (get_query_var('nmbr')) echo "[masterslider id= . $nmbr]" ?>
```

I also tried ob_start with ob_clean without success.

Please help.

Comment: I suspect the moment you apply your shortcode value , content for the page is already loaded. How are you editing the shortcode's id, I mean at which hook/filter. Have you tried the_content filter? https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content

Comment: Thanks for your response. The issue is solved. I was so obsessed by the shortcode in square brackets that I overlooked the corresponding php function for the shortcode. Now I created a custom-page with the php-function below the header-call. It works fine. I have now one page where I can display every slider, according to their "id".

Comment: Great that you got it resolved! I have posted my comment as answer you may mark it resolved to mark this question resolved. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the moment you apply your short-code value , content for the page is already loaded. So it never gets executed.

So I would try adding  the_content filter to add/edit the short-code's ID so it gets changed before content gets displayed.